# Insert into SQL if entry does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert a row into my database table if the value of the first column does not exist in the table.

Example:

```
Name   Value1    Value2
------------------------    
John      2        3
Max       4        6
Alex      0        0
```

Now I want to insert a new person with the values 0 and 0 but only if the person does not exist. For example if I tried to insert John it would not do anything. All of this should happen in one single query.

Can anyone help?

Regards, Max

Answer (score 3):

You can create a unique index on `table(name)` and then use `insert ignore` or `insert on duplicate key update`:

```
create unique index unq_t_name on t(name);

insert into t(name, value1, value2)
    values ($Name, $value1, $value2)
    on duplicate key update name = values(name);
```

The `on duplicate key` is a non-operation -- it does nothing if the name is already in the database.

Comment: Ok, I've tried that and it worked pretty good. The problem is that every time a person that already is in the table get's inserted the console tells me that the key is duplicate

Comment: Perhaps `insert ignore` would prevent the message.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on Name, make it unique. Thereafter you will not be able to add records where the name is already in there.